# System of three equations with lots of symmetry and 6 unexpected (?) solutions.

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials, cubics

I'm interested in the system of equations:

$a(b^2+c)=c(c+ab)$

$b(c^2+a)=a(a+bc)$

$c(a^2+b)=b(b+ac)$

It is easy to see that $a=b=c=t$ are solutions for all $t$, in fact these are the only real solutions.

If we allow complex solutions there are in fact 6 more solutions, after a lot of elementary algebra you can show that the solutions for a are the solutions $(a^3+(-1-i)a^2+a-1)(a^3+(-1+i)a^2+a-1)=0$ and from this you can recover b and c. Can someone give a simple argument for this fact? The argument I have is straightforward but a bit too involved and I have a feeling there might be something easy here.

Comment: what do we know about the variables?

Comment: Nothing really I'm interested in the set of all complex solutions to the equations. I can prove that there are only six solutions beside a=b=c and I can write down formulas for b and c in terms of a in this case and I can find the above equation for a. But the amount of algebra I need seems a bit too much.

Comment: we find $a=b=c=0$ and the complex solutions are the soltuions of a polynomial of degree six

Comment: I know that a=b=c=t are solutions for all t, not only zero. I know that the other solutions come from a degree six polynomial, in fact I gave you the polynomial and a factorization of the polynomial in "nice" parts. I don't understand the point of your comment.